# Warning: require (C:/wamp/www/cricinfo/admin/libs/DB.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: php, wamp

This is PHP file that is causing the error in trying to access the livescore PHP file in the website

```
session_start();

define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'update_score');

spl_autoload_register(function($class_name) {
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/cricinfo/admin/libs/'  . $class_name . '.php';
});

?>
```

spl_autoload error occurs because init PHP file trying to access to the live score PHP file where it suggest that these that these two lines that causing this error.

```
$active=new activeMatch();
$result1=$active->activeTeam();
```

Here is the errors

[image: this is the error]

Comment: What do those functions do? Without seeing them, I'm not sure we can do much. Does the file exist in the location provided?

Comment: no db.php in specified location

Comment: the error caused in this two lines:          spl_autoload_register(function($class_name) {
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/cricinfo/admin/libs/'  . $class_name . '.php';
});

Comment: Why have you tagged `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Does `DB.php` exist in `C:\wamp\www\cricinfo\admin\libs` ??

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the file `DB.php` doesn't exist at the path you've specified.